# No data when attempting to get JSONP data from cross domain PHP script

Tags: php, jquery, jsonp

I am trying to pull latitude and longitude values from another server on a different domain using a singe id string. I am not very familiar with JQuery, but it seems to be the easiest way to go about getting around the same origin problem. I am unable to use iframes and I cannot install PHP on the server running this javascript, which is forcing my hand on this.

My queries appear to be going through properly, but I am not getting any results back. I was hoping someone here might have an idea that could help, seeing as I probably wouldn't recognize most obvious errors here.

My javascript function is:

```
var surl = "http://...omitted.../pull.php";
var idnum = 5a; //in practice this is defined above

alert("BEFORE");

$.ajax({
    url: surl,
    data: {id: idnum},
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonp : "callback",
    jsonp: "jsonpcallback",
    success: function (rdata) {
        alert(rdata.lat + ", " + rdata.lon);
    }
});

alert("BETWEEN");

function jsonpcallback(rtndata) {
    alert("CALLED");
    alert(rtndata.lat + ", " + rtndata.lon);
}

    alert("AFTER");
```

When my javascript is run, the BEFORE, BETWEEN and AFTER alerts are displayed. The CALLED and other jsonpcallback alerts are not shown.

Is there another way to tell if the jsoncallback function has been called?

Below is the PHP code I have running on the second server. I added the count table to my database just so that I can tell when this script is run. Every time I call the javascript, count has had an extra item inserted and the id number is correct.

```
<?php

    header("content-type: application/json");

if (isset($_GET['id']) || isset($_POST['id'])){

    $db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);
    if (!$db_handle)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);
    if ($db_found)
    {
        if (isset($_POST['id'])){
            $SQL = sprintf("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE loc_id='%s'", $loctable, mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']));
        } 
        if (isset($_GET['id'])){
            $SQL = sprintf("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE loc_id='%s'", $loctable, mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']));
        }
        $result = mysql_query($SQL, $db_handle);
        $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

        $rtnjsonobj -> lat = $db_field["lat"];
        $rtnjsonobj -> lon = $db_field["lon"];

        if (isset($_POST['id'])){
            echo $_POST['jsonpcallback']. '('. json_encode($rtnjsonobj) . ')';
        } 
        if (isset($_GET['id'])){
            echo $_GET['jsonpcallback']. '('. json_encode($rtnjsonobj) . ')';
        }

        $SQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO count (bullshit) VALUES ('%s')", $_GET['id']);
        $result = mysql_query($SQL, $db_handle);
        $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    }

    mysql_close($db_handle);
} else {
    $rtnjsonobj -> lat = 404;
    $rtnjsonobj -> lon = 404;
    echo $_GET['jsonpcallback']. '('. json_encode($rtnjsonobj) . ')';
}?>
```

I am not entirely sure if the jsonp returned by this PHP is correct. When I go directly to the PHP script without including any parameters, I do get the following.

```
 ({"lat":404,"lon":404})
```

The callback function is not included, but that much can be expected when it isn't included in the original call.

Does anyone have any idea what might be going wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure if I properly understood, but you cannot do cross-domain requests using the $.ajax function.

Comment: @Christian Joudrey: you can, with `jsonp`

Comment: @zerkms My bad, didn't notice he set `jsonp`. In that case, you might want to check in your resources console (i.e. Firebug Net tab) to see what your PHP script is returning and whether the good URL is being called.

Comment: I've never used firebug before, but trying it out seems to have shown me where my problem is. Thank you! It's appending a PHP error message to the end of what should be jsonp, but those warnings were coming from the count(bullshit) table, which is extraneous. Removing it and I still find that jsonpcallback is never called, but success is called.

Comment: I still can't get the jsonpcallback function to run, or this entire function to run more than once. I have been able to recover a single lat,lon pair though. This is a good start. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change this part of the code

```
jsonp: "jsonpcallback",
```

with:

```
jsonpCallback : "jsonpcallback",
```

Comment: I tried out your suggestion, and it doesn't seem to work. Making that change actually stops my success function from being called and does not end up making a call to jsoncallback. I guess an explanation of what this change would do might help.

Comment: Basically your PHP should output jsonpcallback({"lat":404,"lon":404}), I'm not sure that you need to override the jsonpcallback parameter...